# Rest-Client: how to post multipart/form-data?

Tags: ruby, curl, http-headers, multipartform-data, rest-client

I have to implement the curl POST request below listed, in Ruby, using Rest-Client.

I have to:

- send params in header;
- send params (that do not contain a file) as `multipart/form-data`:

  ```
  $ curl -X POST -i -H "Authorization: Bearer 2687787877876666686b213e92aa3ec7e1afeeb560000000001" \
      https://api.somewhere.com/endpoint -F sku_id=608399
  ```

How can I translate the curl request using the RestClient rubygem?

Reading documentation (multipart paragraph): https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client
I coded as:

```
@access_token = 2687787877876666686b213e92aa3ec7e1afeeb560000000001
url = 'https://api.somewhere.com/endpoint'
req = { authorization: "Bearer #{@access_token}"}


RestClient.post url, req, {:sku_id => 608399, :multipart => true}
```

But I get a server error; is the Ruby code above correct?

Thanks a lot,
Giorgio

Comment: Can you try using the headers as a hash: { :authorization => "Bearer #{@access_token}"} ? Also, if it still throws an error, share the error trace here, so we can see what's happening.

Comment: Hi Xammy I got a http status code 401, but, as confirmed by server side guys, it's not a question of wrong access token (the hash run smoothley woith others api endpoints)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's code not valid for `RestClient` implementation.
`headers` should follow after `payload`.

```
module RestClient 
 def self.post(url, payload, headers={}, &block)
  ...
 end
end
```

**UPDATE**

`@access_token` should be a string `"2687787877876666686b213e92aa3ec7e1afeeb560000000001"`

then

```
RestClient.log = 'stdout'
RestClient.post url, {:sku_id => 608399, :multipart => true}, req
```

and log

```
RestClient.post "https://api.somewhere.com/endpoint", "--330686\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"sku_id\"\r\n\r\n608399\r\n--330686--\r\n", "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Authorization"=>"Bearer 2687787877876666686b213e92aa3ec7e1afeeb560000000001", "Content-Length"=>"79", "Content-Type"=>"multipart/form-data; boundary=330686"
```

Comment: Oh you are right, Dmitry, so `RestClient.post url, {:sku_id => 608399, :multipart => true}, req` could be best :-) so the question is: can submit a payload as multipart/form-data as in the code here ?

Comment: thanks, SOLVED! as you wrote, btw, yes: access token is a string, my typo:-( only a minor note: `RestClient.log = 'stdout'` do not work for me, but that's another story. Thanks for your patience

Comment: sure. Maybe you use different version of `rest-client`, got it from here https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient.rb#L117

Answer (score 10):

Since I had trouble understanding the example Dmitry showed, here is an example for creating a Multipart request to upload an image:

```
response = RestClient.post 'https://yourhost.com/endpoint',

{:u_id => 123, :file => File.new('User/you/D/cat.png', 'rb'), :multipart => true},

{:auth_token => xyz5twblah, :cookies => {'_cookie_session_name' => cookie}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to send both xml and a file in one POST, and your example worked for me.